# Prove for $ |x|<\frac{1}{2}, x-x^2\le \log(x+1)\le x$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality, logarithms

I need to prove for $|x|<\frac{1}{2}, x-x^2\le \log(x+1)\le x$. I thought about MVT and Taylor series but nothing seems to work. May I please ask for a proof? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The right inequality is convexity. $f\colon x\mapsto \ln(1+x)$ is concave, and $f'(0) = 1$, so $$
   \ln(1+x) = f(x) \leq f(0)+f'(0)x = x$$
   for every $x\geq -1$. (The function is below its tangent at $0$).

   *As often for convexity arguments: looking at the graph would help you.*
2. The left inequality can be shown by calculus. Define $g\colon [-1,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ by $$g(x) \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \ln(1+x)-(x-x^2).$$
   Then, for any $x>-1$, $g'(x) = \frac{x(1+2x)}{1+x}$ which cancels only at $\frac{-1}{2}$ and $0$, and is

   - negative on $(-\frac{1}{2},0)$;
   - positive on $(0,\infty)$.

   It follows that $g$ is decreasing on $(-\frac{1}{2},0)$ and increasing afterwards; since $g(0) = 0$, we have $g\geq 0$ on $(-\frac{1}{2},\infty)$.