# Find all possible values of $p$ such that $\sum_{k=2}^∞ ln(1+\frac{(- 1)^k}{k^p}) $ Converges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

This is a calculus homework question:

> Find all possible values of $p$ such that: $$\sum_{k=2}^\infty
>  \ln\left(1+\frac{(-1)^k}{k^p}\right)$$Converges.

I tried to use comprasion test, But all candidates failed to achieve the desired result.

I already spent alot of time on it, so any assistance will be useful.

Comment: Just being curious : what is *a lot of time* ? I am serious since it is a very relative concept

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Around 5 hours.

Comment: If you meant $p \in \Bbb{R}$ then what do you get for $p > 1$? For $p\in (1/2,1]$ ? For $p=1/2$ ? For $p < 1/2$ grouping the terms by two will help

Comment: Use this estimate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2267122/42969.

Comment: Or see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/597060/42969, or here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3239056/42969, or here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/541672/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D2%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%20%5Cln%5Cleft(1%2B%5Cfrac%7B(-1)%5Ek%7D%7Bk%5Ep%7D%5Cright)%24)